# java multiplying numbers get from the input

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem with multiplying numbers.

From my input I get:

- number of digits of the number
- how many numbers i have to multiply

Example: if I get from the input `3,2` it means I need to multiply all **two** digits numbers **three** times

For now I got some code which works only when I get two numbers with two digits.

How can I implement a method which multiplies as many numbers as user need? I made only this kind of method which prints number of digits got from the input. I can handle method which can multiply them as many times as variable multiplier says...

```
public static void test(int digits, int multiplier) {

    int number = 0;
    int result = 0;
    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    number = (int) Math.pow(10, digits);
    for (int i = (int) (Math.pow(10, digits - 1)); i < number; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        for (int j = (int) (Math.pow(10, digits - 1)); j < number; j++) {
            result = j * i;

        }

    }

    System.out.println(number);

}
```

**Sample Input And Output**

If number of digits = 2, number of times = 2

We need to multiply all 2 digit numbers `10, 11, 12 .... 99` two times.

```
10 * 10
10 * 11
.
.
10 * 99
.
.
.
99 * 98
99 * 98
```

In the same way, if the no of digits is 2, and the no of times is 3

```
10 * 10 * 10
10 * 10 * 11
.
.
10 * 99 * 99
.
.
.
99 * 99 * 98
99 * 99 * 99
```

Comment: the constraints are rather confusing... could you elaborate? and you should use `Math.round(double)` instead of casting to `int` (precision!!!!!).

Comment: why are you even considering number of digits?

Comment: thank you very much i will change it to Math.round. so i need some algorithm which get 2 numbers from the input and first number is a number which will be using for multiplying for example 2,3- means i need to multiply all two digits numbers three times...10 * 10 * 11,10*10 * 12,10*10*13...99*99*99, but when input will be 2,2 i need to multiply  all two digits numbers two times: 10*10,10*11...99*99

Comment: Please define clear examples of input and expected output in your quesiton.

Comment: do you have to add the result of each of the multiplications?

Comment: @thosenumbers what should be your output? sum of all these multiplications?

Comment: @anish Maybe displaying it in a String like `10 * 10 ..` so that the OP could learn how to get the numbers.

Comment: @anish - no i do not have to add reuslt of each multiplication

Comment: @karthi my output should be the result of all those multiplictaions ( input:2,2 so output is a result of multipliacting 10*10,10*11,10*12...99*99)

Comment: sorry OUTPUT need to be result of EACH not ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use recursion, but use a for loop in combination with the **Java8 streaming API**.

The code example:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Multiplier {

    private final int digits;

    public Multiplier(int digits) {
        this.digits = digits;
    }

    /**
     * @param multiplificationSteps
     * @return a stream, containing all numbers of the given digits, each multiplied several times with each other
     * 
     * digits=1 with multiplificationSteps=1 => output [1;9] 
     * digits=2 with multiplificationSteps=1 => output [10;99] 
     * digits=1 with multiplificationSteps=2 => output [1;9] & [2;19] & ... & [9;81] 
     */
    public IntStream createFullStream(int multiplificationSteps) {
        IntStream intStream = makeIntStream();
        for (int i = 1; i < multiplificationSteps; i++)
            intStream = intStream.flatMap(this::multiplyStream);
        return intStream;
    }

    /**
     * @param input a multiplier
     * @return the stream, having each number multiplied by the multiplier
     * 
     * input [1;9]   and 1 => output [1;9]
     * input [1;9]   and 2 => output [2;18]
     * input [10;99] and 3 => output [30;297]
     */
    private IntStream multiplyStream(int input) {
        return makeIntStream().map(k -> input * k);
    }

    /**
     * @return a stream of all numbers with the given number of digits
     * 
     * input 1 => output [1;9]
     * input 2 => output [10;99]
     * input 3 => output [100;999]
     */
    private IntStream makeIntStream() {
        int startNumber = (int) Math.pow(10, digits - 1);
        int endNumber   = (int) Math.pow(10, digits);
        return IntStream.range(startNumber, endNumber);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Multiplier(1).createFullStream(2).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

---

**sample input and outputs**

For the input `1,1` it outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

For `1,2` it outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
4
8
12
16
20
24
28
32
36
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
6
12
18
24
30
36
42
48
54
7
14
21
28
35
42
49
56
63
8
16
24
32
40
48
56
64
72
9
18
27
36
45
54
63
72
81
```

---

it also will work **without Java8**

```
import java.util.*;

public class PlainOldMultiplier {

    private final int digits;

    public PlainOldMultiplier(int digits) {
        this.digits = digits;
    }

    public void printAllMultipliedNumbers(int multiplicationSteps) {

        // define the result
        Collection<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(1);// multiply by 1 in first iteration

        // foreach multiplicationStep once multiply all existing stuff with [start;end[
        for (int multiplicationStepCount = 0; multiplicationStepCount < multiplicationSteps; multiplicationStepCount++) {
            numbers = multiplyEverything(numbers);
        }

        // output numbers to console
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    private Collection<Integer> multiplyEverything(Collection<Integer> numbersOfPreviousIteration) {
        Collection<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // define start and end by taking account "digits"
        int start = (int) Math.pow(10, digits-1);
        int end   = (int) Math.pow(10, digits);

        // foreach number within [start;end[ multiply existing stuff
        for (int number = start; number < end; number++) {

            for (Integer numberOfPreviousIteration : numbersOfPreviousIteration) {
                result.add(numberOfPreviousIteration * number);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PlainOldMultiplier(1).printAllMultipliedNumbers(1); // outputs [1;9]
        new PlainOldMultiplier(2).printAllMultipliedNumbers(1); // outputs [10;99]
        new PlainOldMultiplier(1).printAllMultipliedNumbers(2); // outputs [1;9] & [2;18] & ... & [9;81]
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But is there any other solution which doesn't use Java 8. Using just loops?

Comment: @UmaKanth You didn't mention that in your question... Why not using Java8?

Comment: I'd put the question the other way around. There should be a way to clear that loop and stick to streams only.

Comment: @UmaKanth I added the code for doing it without Java8.

Comment: thank you very much for ur answers i'll try to understand your code as im learning java now so it's not easy for me;) thank once again